# Ошибка в AsyncTask при работе с ListView Adapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listview, android-sqlite

Вобщем я создал кастомный адаптер  который инициализирую в AsyncTask,  в методе onPostExecute я вызываю другой AsyncTask  который проверяет новые заказы на сервере, но перед этим он идет в базу данных и смотрит какой последний номер заказа что бы определить с какого номера искать новые и в этом месте он падает(при походе в БД). При этом на эмуляторе я вижу либо черный экран с ошибкой:

```
12-10 16:32:21.921  13500-13507/? E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
12-10 16:32:21.921  13500-13507/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
```

Либо вижу целую простыню с ошибками и приложение закрывается. При этом со стандартным ArrayAdapter такого не было.

```
12-10 16:26:06.233  10651-10699/com.root.ecoistdemo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:962)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:599)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:348)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:894)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:834)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:196)
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:236)
            at com.root.ecoistdemo.DAO.impl.OrderDAO.getLastId(OrderDAO.java:175)
            at com.root.ecoistdemo.util.CheckNewOrders.check(CheckNewOrders.java:19)
            at com.root.ecoistdemo.activity.OrdersActivity$checkNewOrdersOnServer.doInBackground(OrdersActivity.java:156)
            at com.root.ecoistdemo.activity.OrdersActivity$checkNewOrdersOnServer.doInBackground(OrdersActivity.java:152)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Ниже код обоих AsyncTask

```
public class GetOrders extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private OrdersActivity activity;

    public GetOrders(OrdersActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(OrdersActivity.this);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Обновление списка заказов");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg) {

        orderList = new OrderDAO(getApplicationContext()).getOrderList();

        for (Order order : orderList) {
            order.setPosition(new OrderPositionDAO(getApplicationContext()).getOrderPositionList(order.getId()));
        }
        listadapter = new OrdersListAdapter(OrdersActivity.this, (ArrayList<Order>) orderList);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (success){  new checkNewOrdersOnServer().execute() }

        listView.setAdapter(listadapter);
    }
}

public class checkNewOrdersOnServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (IsOnline.check(getApplicationContext())){
            if (CheckNewOrders.check(OrdersActivity.this)){
                return true;
            }
        }else {
            return false;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        if (aBoolean == null){
        }else {
            if (aBoolean){
                CheckNewOrders.showDialog(OrdersActivity.this);
            }
            if (!aBoolean){
                IsOnline.showDialog(OrdersActivity.this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ок. Вынес вызов второго AsyncTask из метода onPostExecute() первого AsyncTask в метод onCreate, таким образом:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_orders);

    new GetOrders(OrdersActivity.this).execute();
    new checkNewOrdersOnServer().execute();
    ;}
```

Не знаю почему, но это сработало. Если кто то знает в чем была проблема - объясните мне пожалуйста, почему в предыдущем варианте была ошибка.